# Race condition with Node.js and Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Firebase and Node.js, but what I'm trying to do is the following:

```
gameScoreRef.child(score["ss"][i][10]).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.val()) {
        // NULL
    } else {
        gameID = snapshot.val();
        console.log(gameID);
    }
});

var ref = gamesRef.child(gameID);
ref.update({
    aScore: parseInt(score["ss"][i][5]),
    hScore: parseInt(score["ss"][i][7])
});
```

So basically I am making one Firebase call to get the GameScore Ref and once that is retrieved, which works perfectly, it will use that GameID to update the game score.

The error that is thrown is that the `gameID` is null, and not because Firebase actually has null, the value is displayed correctly with the `console.log(gameID)` as 43, its because it seems that the first Firebase call has not finished before the second Firebase call, to update the scores is reached?

How would I resolve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the code below `gameScoreRef.child` inside it's callback. `gameScoreRef.child` is an asynchronous function, `gameID` doesn't exist when you're using it in `gamesRef.child(gameID)`.

```
 gameScoreRef.child(score["ss"][i][10]).once('value', function(snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.val()) {
            // NULL
        } else {
            gameID = snapshot.val();
            console.log(gameID);
            var ref = gamesRef.child(gameID);
            ref.update({
               aScore: parseInt(score["ss"][i][5]),
               hScore: parseInt(score["ss"][i][7])
            });
        }



    });

    // "gameID" doesn't exist here!
```

Or you can make a `retrieveScore` function that returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```
function retrieveScore(ref){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        gameScoreRef.child(ref).once('value', snapshot => {
            if (!snapshot.val()) {
                return reject();

            resolve(snapshot.val());

        });
    });

}


retrieveScore(score["ss"][i][10]).then(gameID => {
    console.log(gameID);
    let ref = gamesRef.child(gameID);
    ref.update({
        aScore: parseInt(score["ss"][i][5]),
        hScore: parseInt(score["ss"][i][7])
    });

}).catch(err => {
   //Handle error
});
```

Check this questions:

- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)
- [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function?rq=1)

Comment: case 1: this causes the same issue with gameID being null at that time of the call.

Comment: @learningiOS check my edited answer, `gamesRef.child(gameID)` is inside the `else` block, is the `console.log` is being printed correctly?

Comment: Can you add a console.log inside `catch` and tell me if anything is printed there?

Comment: I can't test your code, but if `gameScoreRef.child` works as you put in your code sample, my code should work.

Comment: I coded it the way you have with the correction where you did not complete the if else pairing; but it still does not work. In the retrieveScore function the gameScoreRef.child(ref).once(... never gets called!?

Comment: @learningiOS if `once` never gets called there isn't a problem with my code, there is a problem with your code (which you didn't show). My code works, tested it serveral times. So please provide a little more code so we can help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142216/discussion-between-marcos-casagrande-and-learningios).

Comment: i put some error code and i get the follwoing: TypeError: Cannot read property '5' of undefined
    at getScores.then.gameID (/Users/sguerrera/NodeJS/getnflscores:216:60)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)